# Carriage Return isn't being removed from exported .csv in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I currently have an update query that is using Replace([field name], Chr(13) & Chr(10), "") on 3 fields in my table.  For two of the fields it removes the carriage return, but for the last field it doesn't.

Have you come across this before?  Carriage returns being removed for two fields but not another. Could there be another issue for why my one specific field is returning a line in the csv?

Comment: Are you sure all of the carriage returns have both characters? Try doing nested replaces and see if that clears the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using two steps:

```
Replace(Replace([field name], Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), "")
```